# Does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} ((-1)^n+\frac{1}{n})$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$c_n=\sum _{n=1}^{ \infty}\frac{1}{n} ((-1)^n+\frac{1}{n})
=\sum _{n=1}^{ \infty}\frac{1}{n} (-1)^n +\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

$a_n=\sum _{n=1}^{ \infty}\frac{1}{n} (-1)^n$

$b_n=\sum _{n=1}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$

1. By the alternating series test, $a_n$ converges.
2. By the p-series test, $b_n$ converges.

So that $c_n(=a_n+b_n)$ converges.

Was this the correct way to show that $c$ converges?
Can I say that the whole serie converges if every single term of the sum of this serie converges ?

Comment: I think you want  $n=1$ under the summation sign. Also you can just write $\infty$ instead of $n\to \infty$ on top.

Comment: thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: No, you haven't. You've corrected some of the lower limits and none of the upper limits. Also ("$c=a+b$ converges") is rather vague; this should say something like "$\sum_na_n$ converges and $\sum_nb_n$ converges and $c_n=a_n+b_n$; thus $\sum_nc_n$ converges.".)

Comment: As a matter of interest, notice that the series does not converge absolutely. For if we set $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}( (-1)^{n} + \frac{1}{n}),$ then $|a_{n}| \geq \frac{1}{2n}$ for $n \geq 2.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The sum of two convergent series again converges.

That is, if you know that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n
$$
both converge with sums $a$ and $b$ respectively, then you know that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n + b_n
$$
is convergent with sum $a+b$.

You have simply applied this fact to the example where
$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\quad\text{and}\quad b_n= \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$

As a matter of "logic" I would first note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. Then note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges. Then, with the convergence of the two series, you conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n + b_n$ is convergent.

Comment: THOMAS@9,999 . Great innings.

Comment: @exploringnet: It is like Christmas Eve :)

Comment: Yes you are gonna be like a moderator ♦ soon!

Comment: And I help you for the last runs , +1 for this.

Comment: @exploringnet: Thanks :)